# Preset Safari Bookmarks and Homepage Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

So I want to have it that whenever I create a new user and they launch Safari for the first time it brings up a Preset homepage "www.homepage.net" and it already has a set of bookmarks I would like already imported.
This is in an office setting with 100+ machines (Mac Minis) on El Capitan.

The goal is to be able to Create a new user on any machine and the first time it opens Safari the bookmarks and homepage are already set to what I want it to be set to. That way I can give new users a set of helpful bookmarks for them to use.

I have done this with Chrome and Firefox but Safari is not my area of expertise, if this is possible I would greatly appreciate any help or information you can give me. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have looked at some other solutions but they are so old and outdated that the files they say to modify no longer exist in the location they specified.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution, its not the best but it was the only one I could find.

So my first step was to use the command

"defaults write com.apple.Safari NewWindowBehavior -int 0 " 
 this command changes the setting to start at homepage not favorites page.

Then the command to set the homepage is

defaults write com.apple.Safari HomePage "http://www.homepage.net"

And now for the bookmark portion I will be using a LaunchAgent/ If then else script.

/Users/Bilbo/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist is the location of the bookmarks for your user. I made my own bookmark.plist and when a user first logs in, the LaunchAgent runs the script to add that file to that folder to create a "default" list of bookmarks. The reason I added an If-Then-Else to the script is to prevent this script from overwriting any users personal bookmarks.

If the file already exists do not place the new file there. So this would only work for a new user.

Hopefully I explained it well enough.